# Problema com switch C

Tags: c, switch

Tenho um código em C, e sem o switch, funciona certinho, mas com switch, ao inserir nome na lista, substitui todos os nome da lista pelo mesmo.

```
void insChild(LIST* l, char name[]) {
  NO* new;
  NO* p;
  p = LastChild(*l);
  new = (NO*)malloc(sizeof(NO));
  new->child = name;
  new->next = l->head;
  p->next = new;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema principal está na atribuição do nome na inserção de um novo elemento na lista:

```
void insChild(LIST* l, char name[]) {
  ...
  NO* new;
  ...
  new = (NO*)malloc(sizeof(NO));
  new->child = name; //<---aqui
```

Sendo `child` um ponteiro, ele irá ficar a apontar para a variável passada como parâmetro:

```
scanf("%s", name /*<---esta*/);
```

E cada vez que insere outro nó irá ficar a apontar para a mesma variável `name`. O que quer fazer é na verdade alocar espaço para uma nova `string` com `malloc` e copiar do nome para essa `string` com `strcpy`:

```
void insChild(LIST* l, char name[])
{
    ...
    NO* new;
    ...
    new = (NO*)malloc(sizeof(NO));
    new->child = malloc((strlen(name)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(new->child,name);
```

Note que eu usei o `strlen` para descobrir o tamanho do nome e alocar uma `string` com esse tamanho. Esse tamanho teve de ser aumentado em `1` para contemplar o terminador `\0` da `string`. Tudo isto irá implica acrescentar a referência ao `string.h`:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Documentação para o [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) e para o [`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/)

**Outros problemas**

O problema dos nomes ficou resolvido, mas ainda tem algumas coisas que precisa de acertar e pode melhorar:

- Todas as funções que recebem `LIST` devem passar a receber `LIST*` pois isto evita a copia da estrutura toda na chamada à função
- Não deve utilizar `new` como nome de variavel e irá trazer lhe problemas se migrar o código para C++, pois nele será uma palavra reservada
- O *Segmentation Fault* que indicou nos comentários deve-se a função de achar do nó a remover. Não só a condição devia ser alterada como faltou iniciar o ponteiro `bef`. Deveria antes ficar assim:

  ```
  NO* nChild(LIST *l, int n, NO** bef)
  {
      NO* p = l->head->next;

      //faltou aqui iniciar o ponteiro que ficava inválido não houvessem elementos
      *bef = l->head; 
      int i = 0;

      //ajustei aqui para n, e int del = rand() % slist; na função DelChild
      while ((p != l->head) && (i < n))  
      {
          *bef = p;
          p = p->next;
          i++;
      }
      if (i >= SizeList(l)) return NULL; //troquei a condição para facilitar
      else return p;
  }
  ```

[Veja o código com todas estas alterações a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/6vtAeC)

Comment: Valeu Isac, deu certinho, mas agora deu um problema de segmentation fault. Ao inserir "Ana", "Bana" e "Joao" e ir removendo, na segunda vez da segmentation fault. Saberia me dizer o porquê?

Comment: @Juny Tem mais problemas para além da copia em si. Já os indico mal tenha agora um pouco de tempo.

Comment: Beleza @Isac, sem pressa. Fico no aguardo. Obrigado!

Comment: @Juny Já editei a pergunta, assinalando as coisas a melhorar/corrigir, e agora está a funcionar mesmo a parte de remover